# how can I stop mint/mate before the mate environment loads

Tags: login, text, mate-desktop

I have a mint 20 install with mate. I ran out of disk space on the boot device. I booted off an external medium, erased files and now have a residual issue with Mate. I had the system configured to boot to a mate desktop without asking for a password. Now the startup halts at the credential screen asking for a password. No matter what key I press the screen clears and after a short delay returns to the credential screen, but does not halt, just keeps blanking and looping on the login.

I'd like to stop the startup process at a text screen so I can diagnose and perhaps reinstall Mate. But I don't know how. Suggestions?